# Links on the left bar of the theme ain't working in liferay 6.1.2 GA3

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, liferay-6

I'm very new to Liferay. I'm facing a problem in deployment. I'm using **Liferay 6.1.2 GA3** along with **MySQL Database** on **RHEL 6.x** .

I've a design basis on which I've developed the theme of liferay. And the design is so that it divides a page in three parts which are

1. Upper Doc-bar i.e. bearing the Liferay's out-of-box functionality.
2. Side bar i.e. menu bar.
3. Portlet part i.e. where the portlets are placed.

Now **.war** file of this theme project is working absolutely fine in **Windows Environment**. But when I deploy it in **Linux VM** of my machine it doesn't behave as it should. Any of Links on the side bar doesn't work at all.

**Please suggest me a solution. And do tell me if I'm making mistake(s) in development or deployment.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two solutions which helped us in similar problems:

First one, give a try to add to your address **?js_fast_load=0** param in end of the url.

Another solution which helped us in similar js problems not expandable menu etc. was to:

In file liferay/tomcat/bin/**setenv.sh**

to variable **JAVA_OPTS** add param

```
  -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties
```

At the end, this should look like:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Duser.timezone=GMT -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dexternal-properties=portal-developer.properties"
```

Next in the file liferay/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/**portal-developer.properties**

Change param

```
javascript.fast.load=false
```

and add

```
com.liferay.portal.servlet.filters.minifier.MinifierFilter=false
```

Restart your server. I assumed you are using tomcat server.

Comment: It ain't using JavaScript. That's why it didn't work.